# throw runTime exception on child thread causing main parent thread to end, why?

Tags: android, multithreading, exception

In Android, but could be in any Java program, i spawn a child thread which throws a `RunTimeException`. The code looks like this:

```
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            throw new RuntimeException();
        }
    }).start();
```

This completely terminates my application with FatalException error. I thought that only the child thread would end but the main/parent thread can continue ? is this assumption not correct ?

Comment: In normal java it will not terminate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RuntimeException will usually only kill the thread, but can kill the program. Other things are usually the determinant of this. Would need to see more code, but it may be an issue with androids exception handling in threads.

Comment: @j2emanue was it in your main Java file? Recreated your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Android only having main (single) thread.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure you can create your own exceptions and do a stopSelf() on the child thread. Not sure exactly what you're trying to do or I'd give an example.

```
Runnable r = new Runnable()
{
    public void run() {
    while (/*whatever you want to determine end of thread*/)
    {
        try { // this stuff
        } catch (Exception e) { // exception handling
        }
    }
    stopSelf();
    }
};

//Thread start code
```

this should work and not crash your app...

Comment: actually i am just asking about fundamental behavior.  Should a run time exception thats thrown on a child thread end the parent thread also ? in my test on android its doing this but someone mentioned on java its not so i dont know what is the expected behavior. Whats the rule ?

Comment: RuntimeException will usually only kill the thread, but can kill the program even in java.  Other things are usually the determinant of this.  would need to see more code, but it may be an issue with androids exception handling in threads.

Comment: i see, you can make this an official answer for consideration.